# Ninject is not generating WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl, ninject

I just started playing with Ninject for self hosted WCF services.

I ran into a problem where it isnt generating a wsdl (url?wsdl or url?singleWsdl).

I start up the service with this :

```
 private static void StartNinjectSelfHost()
    {
        var someWcfService = NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<CalculatorService, NinjectWebServiceSelfHostFactory>();

        _selfHost = new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(CreateKernel,someWcfService);

        _selfHost.Start();
    }
```

If I revert to the standard way with this:

```
private static void LoadWcf()
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
    // provide the base address.
    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

    // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
    // listening for messages.
    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Then I get the wsdl just fine at this URL: 
http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service?singleWsdl

I'm guessing I have to tell Ninject to do this, but I'm struggling to find any good info by searching.

Any help on enabling the wsdl is appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind I'm dumb. I wanted to use "NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory" instead, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I'm dumb. I wanted to use "NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory" instead, now it works